# How to get payment method for the products which is placed under buy 1 get 1 50%

Tags: magento-1.9

I the customer placing order for the product which is placed under BUY 1 GET 1 50%.
But when i place order am getting struck at shipping method.
Can i know why it is happening like this and what changes should i do to get shipping method?
Can someone suggest me?

Comment: Your Question is not clear.. please post clearly what you want to achieve and what you have done so far